# RX Java 2 onComplete method called for every Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm new to RX Java. I need to execute in asynchronous mode some works and get a callback when ALL works are done. I've placed some Log.d into callbacks methods, and I see that the onComplete (and onNext as well) methods are executed for every completed jobs, but this is not my desidered behavior.
Also, I'm unable to resubmit new jobs if I call the dispose method because threads just doesn't starts and I have to set null to the reference of my class containing RX Java methods and create a new Instance.

P.S. please avoid lambda expressions

That's my code:

```
 public class Async2 {
    
        private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        private ArrayList<FileRepresentation> fileRepresentationList = null;
    
    
        public Async2() {
            fileRepresentationList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        }
    
        public ArrayList<FileRepresentation> getFileRepresentationList() {
            return fileRepresentationList;
        }
    
        public void dispose(){
            disposables.dispose();
    
        }
    
    
        public Observable<FileRepresentation> calcObservable(Uri uri, Context context) {
            return Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends FileRepresentation>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<? extends FileRepresentation> call() {
    
                    FileUtils fu = new FileUtils();
    
                    FileRepresentation fileRepresentation = FileUtils.calcolaChecksumFromUri(uri, context); //this is the long running job
    
                    Log.d("test-0X", fileRepresentation.nome);
                    Log.d("test-0X", fileRepresentation.hash);
                    Log.d("Thread name: ", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    
    
                    FileRepresentation finalFileRepresentation = fileRepresentation;
                    //return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(finalFileRepresentation));
                    return Observable.just(finalFileRepresentation);
                }
            });
        }
    
    
    
        //
    
    
        public void addWorks(List<Uri> uriList, Context context, CommunicationInterface com){
    
            fileRepresentationList.clear();
    
            int nObservable = uriList.size();
            AtomicInteger remainings = new AtomicInteger(nObservable);
    
            disposables.clear();
            com.enableProgressBar();
    
            Disposable[] disposableArr = new Disposable[nObservable];
            Log.d("addworks", "addWorks method (nObservable var): "+nObservable);
            Log.d("addworks", "addWorks method (disposable.size() ): "+disposables.size());
            for (int i= 0; i<nObservable; i++){
                Disposable disposable = calcObservable(uriList.get(i), context)
                        // Run on a background thread
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                        // Be notified on the main thread
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<FileRepresentation>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {
                                if(remainings.decrementAndGet() == 0){
                                    Log.d("Method onComplete called", "elementi lista: "+fileRepresentationList.size());
                                    Log.d("Method onComplete called", "End!!");
                                    com.disableProgressBar();
                                    com.notifyCompletion();
                                }
                                com.updateProgress();
Log.d("Method onComplete called", "End!!");
    
                            }
    
                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                if(remainings.decrementAndGet() == 0){
                                    Log.d("Method onError", "elementi lista: "+fileRepresentationList.size());
                                    Log.d("Method onError", "End!!");
                                    com.disableProgressBar();
                                    com.notifyCompletion();
                                }
    
                                com.updateProgress();
    
                                Log.d("method onError", "method onError called");
    
                            }
    
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(FileRepresentation value) {
    
                                fileRepresentationList.add(value);
                            }
                        });
    
                disposableArr[i] = disposable;
    
            }
            disposables.addAll(disposableArr);
            Log.d("addworks", "addWorks method (disposable.size() ): "+disposables.size());
    
        }
    
    }
```

Here I start works:

```
 ArrayList<FileRepresentation> li = async2.getFileRepresentationList();
```

Comment: When and why are you calling `dispose()`? Calling it means all future work will be disposed immediately.

Comment: I call from the main activity if I want to cancel jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create N observables and observers, just create a flow from the list:

```java
disposables.add(
    Observable.fromIterable(uriList)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .flatMap(new Function<Uri, Observable<FileRepresentation>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<FileRepresentation> apply(Uri uri) {
                return calcObservable(uri, context);
            }
        }, /*delayErrors */ true)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<FileRepresentation>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d("Method onComplete called", "elementi lista: "+fileRepresentationList.size());
                Log.d("Method onComplete called", "End!!");
                com.disableProgressBar();
                com.notifyCompletion();
                Log.d("Method onComplete called", "End!!");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("Method onError", "elementi lista: "+fileRepresentationList.size());
                Log.d("Method onError", "End!!");
                com.disableProgressBar();
                com.notifyCompletion();

                Log.d("method onError", "method onError called");

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(FileRepresentation value) {

                fileRepresentationList.add(value);

                com.updateProgress();
            }
        })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code, but it doesn't work. The "apply" method returns a "FileRepresentation", but in the end of the body, the call to "calcObservable)"  returns a  "Observable<FileRepresentation>" object. I've tried to create a "FileRepresentation" object in the "apply" method and return (only to see if the problem was the incompatible return type), but it didn't worked

Comment: Right, it has to be `Function<Uri, Observable<FileRepresentation>>`.

Comment: Thank you again, but not resolved yet...same problem: 
https://i.imgur.com/lrLpkKa.png

Comment: Did you change `calcObservable` to return `FileRepresentation`? Change it back to `Observable<FileRepresentation>`.

Comment: No, I've not changed the calcObservable. Before I've tried to return a new Object FileRepresentation created inside the "apply" function to test. 
When you answered, I've copy/pasted your code in my method, but Android Studio keeps  complaining about return type, like in the picture above :(

Comment: Updated the answer. It would be much easier if you could use lambdas. Manually typing out datatypes can be error-prone.

Comment: Now is perfectly working, thank you very much!!  I don't use Lambda expression for now because I'm not very  familiar with them, I'll try to learn using them :)